# Is is possible to program the windows 10 desktop to behave and look different?

Tags: windows, windows-10

So, is it possible to turn the win 10 desktop into a 3D grid of sci-fi folders where you fly around to navigate to them?

Or is the desktop code protected by the operating system or something?

Comment: You're asking about the Jurassic Park file manager which [was a real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsn_\(file_manager\)). What you want to find is a *shell replacement* for Windows 10 (these were popular about 20 years ago). Such a question is off-topic for this Stack Exchange site and I'm not even sure if Microsoft allows shell replacements anymore.

Comment: @alroc Wow, had no clue about it. Thank you!